# Ruby on Rails having more than 1 different column foreign keyed to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, foreign-keys

I am very new to Ruby on Rails but I am decent with SQL. I am currently looking at trying to make an association for two tables... well actually more but this one example should answer my question for all. These are fictional but represent my issue so don't mind if they wouldn't follow best practices...

Tables: USER, LOCA   --- They had once limited table name characters back in the day.

-LOCA

LOCATIONID - PK

-USER

USERID - PK; LIVES_LOCATION - FK (LOCATIONID); WORKS_LOCATION - FK (LOCATIONID); MANAGERID....... etc

How do in Ruby on Rails, make the class with belongs_to and has_many with the correct foreign_key names to the correct columns?

Comment: What is the association between  USER &  LOCA ?

Comment: The USER has living location and a working location. LOCA is location with a locationid

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" along with their linked pages. Your question isn't asked well. Formatting is extremely important as it helps us understand your question, which in return helps you. Questions on SO are not only to help you, they are to help others in the future with similar problems, so you have to provide us with sufficient information, written concisely and clearly to help us, and them, understand.

Comment: Ignorant/uninformed is not stupid. (However, regarding the phrasing of your question, you now have links to inform you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class User
  belongs_to :lives, class_name: 'Loca', foreign_key: 'lives_location'
  belongs_to :works, class_name: 'Loca', foreign_key: 'works_location'

  ...
end

class Loca
  has_many :users

  ...
end
```

Comment: so the foreign key is the current table's column! thank you so much